# Query with date in Sugar ORM

Tags: android, database, date, sugarorm

Does somebody know how make query to database with condition between two dates. For example:
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE date between "begin" and "end"

Answer (score 1):

It base on what data type your date column use. I usually save it with `varchar(8)` (eg: 20150707). So it's easy to query between two dates:

```
select * from table where date > '20150707'
```